# On which ViewController should I implement FacebookSDK's removeObserver?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am implementing facebook's SDK for iOS into my app. There are two functions however that are supposed to register and unregister for the notifications:

From [Facebook's login to facebook with ios](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/):

> in the **viewDidLoad** method, register for the session change notification you defined in the app delegate by adding this code to the end of the method:
>
> **[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
>
>        addObserver:self
>
>        selector:@selector(sessionStateChanged:)
>
>        name:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
>
>        object:nil];**

and

> Unregister for the notifications by adding the following code to the end of the **didReceiveMemoryWarning** the method:
>
> **[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];**

Since I have quite a few view controllers and all of them should be using facebook's API, I thought I should implement the register/unregister methods in the **applicationDidFinishLoadingWithOptions** (for `register` for notifications)

but I am not sure if and how I should implement the `unregister`'s removeObserver command, because applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning is **not available** for the AppDelegate.

- Is DidReceiveMemoryWarning visiting all the viewControllers of the App?
- Would it be sufficient to unregister in just one of my viewControllers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application delegate **does** receive memory warnings:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

If it didn't, another option would be to use the notification center:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(whatever:)
               name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
             object:nil];
```

That all said, it seems to me that removing the observer on a memory warning is inappropriate. At what point will your reinstate it? But hey, if that's what Facebook recommends...

Comment: gosh, I did not find the didReceiveMemoryWarning function in the docs because of the foolest mistake (match case was ON!) :D So this is a great point. Why is removing the notifications in that function not a good idea ?

Comment: Well, if you start observing the notification when the view is loaded then I assume that that view needs it. If you then remove the observer while the view is visible then that's odd since, as I said, the view needs it...